# Can this logic be written without a loop in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
departure_time,monday,tuesday
25:30:32,      1,     0
20:20:24,      1,     0
```

The above is part of a dataframe in pandas, The departure_time field is wrong, i want to update it to 01:30:32 and the corresponding day column should appear as 0 and tuesday should appear 1.

currently I am writing a for loop which does this, however, is there a better way to do it in pandas?

I stripped the hour from departure_time and made a column departure_time_hour and have written the following loop, however it is taking a lot of time

```
for i in df.index:
    if df.departure_time_hour[i] > 23:
        hour = str(24 - df.departure_time_hour[i])
        rest = df.departure_time_rest[i]
        df.loc[i,'departure_time_updated'] = hour + rest
        if df.monday[i] == 1:
            df.loc[i,'monday_updated'] = 0
        else:
            df.loc[i,'monday_updated'] = 1
    else:
        df.loc[i,'departure_time_updated'] = df.departure_time[i]
        if df.monday[i] == 1:
            df.loc[i,'monday_updated'] = 1
        else:
            df.loc[i,'monday_updated'] == 0
```

Comment: I think it is easier for you to first parse the time into a datetime object, e.g. `df["departure_time"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["departure_time"]) + pd.to_datetime('2019-09-09')`.

Comment: @lijo please add a sample output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```
s=pd.to_timedelta(df.departure_time)

df.iloc[:,0]=pd.to_timedelta(s.dt.seconds,'s')
df.iloc[:,1:]=df.iloc[:,1:].sub(s.dt.days,axis=0).abs()
```

---

```
  departure_time  monday  tuesday
0       01:30:32       0        1
1       20:20:24       1        0
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, it was helpful, I have a couple of followup questions, 1. if the departure time is above for Monday is greater than 48, Tuesday will display 2 in this case right? 2. and what if I have Monday Tuesday and Wednesday as binary columns
?

Comment: @lijo yes, for point 1 Tuesday would be 2 in that case, cannot comment on the second point since I dont know your expected output in that case. I would suggest you raise a fresh question with a sample input and expected output based on the sample input dataframe and this code, also mention exactly what you want (since these were not in the original scope of the question)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!